# About independence and dependence of normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I encountered two interesting questions:

1. $A=X+Y, B=X-Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal distribution.

Can I draw the conclusion that $A$ and $B$ are independent because they form a bivariate normal distribution with $0$ covariance?

1. $C=X^2$ (A Chi-square distribution)

Can I say that $C$ and $X$ is dependent because the value of $C$ depends on $X$?

Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes for a **multivariate normal distribution**, zero correlation if and only if independent. If multivariate is replaced by **marginal**, this no longer holds. See my answer to this post: [Does $0$ correlation imply independence for marginally normal distributions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341559/does-0-correlation-imply-independence-for-marginally-normal-distributions/659137#659137)
2. $C$ is completely determined by $X$, so yes of course true, trivially.

Comment: Thanks Lost1, this is truly helpful

Comment: @PUPIALEX you can accept the answer by pressing tick if you are fully satisfied.