# Is the Sample Mean and the Sample Standard Deviation independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that the Sample mean and the Sample Variance are independent. However, is there a follow up to say that the Sample Mean is independent to the Sample S.D.?

Thanks

Comment: If $X_{1},X_{2},\cdots , X_{n}$ is a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ and if we define 

\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar{X}&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\\
S^{2}&=&\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
then the sample mean $\bar{X}$ and sample variance $S^{2}$ are independent.

Comment: The sample variance and sample standard deviation are completely dependent on each other: both are non-negative and one is the square of the other.  So anything independent of one is also independent of the other

Comment: But this independence holds for _normal_ data only. See item '1967384'.

Comment: @BruceET: you mean this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967384/covariance-zero-for-two-gaussian-variables

Comment: @L.V.Rao: doesn't the fact that $\bar{X}$ appears in the equation for $S^2$ mean that $S^2$ is dependent on $\bar{X}$? Possible I'm not understanding the difference between linear independence and statistical independence... But could you maybe explain your comment in a bit more depth as an answer?

Comment: Functional dependence between $\bar X$ and $S$ is obvious because the former appears in the definition of the latter. However, for normal data (only) $\bar X$ and $S$ are stochastically independent random variables. Proof is trivial for $n=2$ because $\bar X$ is a multiple of $X_1+X_2$ and $S$ is a fcn of $X_1-X_2.$ So easy to see $\bar X$ and $S$ are uncorrelated, which for normal data implies independence. Linear algebra proof for $n > 2$ uses orthogonal matrices. Also can be proved using MGF's. Link illustrates indep for normal data; proves dependence of $\bar X$ and $S$ for beta data.